# How to output a .pvd or xdmf file from FiPy

Tags: output, fipy

From the example documentation, there is the following section:

> FiPy doesn’t plot or output anything unless you tell it to:
>
> ```
>  if __name__ == "__main__":
>      viewer = Viewer(vars=(phi,), datamin=0., datamax=1.)
> ```

I understand that the current configuration would result in an opening of a viewer using the matplotlib or Mayavi viewers. However, I would like to be able to export a .pvd or .xdmf file for consolidating the simulation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FiPy presently has no such capability, although I've experimented a bit with XDMF and multi-timestep Gmsh MSH files, but need to find time to get back to it. You can save individual data snapshots with the [VTKViewer](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.viewers.vtkViewer.html) classes, but not time series.

```
vw = fp.VTKCellViewer(vars=(phi, psi))
vw.plot(filename="myFile.vtk")
```

If there are particular thinks you'd like to see, please update [issue #132](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/132).

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the super quick response! Could I trouble you for an example of the implementation of the VTKViewer to save individual snapshots ?

Comment: It works like all of our other Viewer classes. I've added an example to my answer.